# Sumif with date condition from a different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know if there is a feature in the SQL that allows you to calculate the sum based on a date condition. The issue I am facing is that date has to pick up from a different table.

Here is my code (This one works fine):

```
SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, p.customer_id, SUM(p.amount)
FROM payment p, customer c
WHERE c.customer_id = p.customer_id
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 4 DESC
```

Table Details are as follows:

```
Payment Table 

Payment ID  Customer_ID First_Name Last_Name  Amount Payment Date
1            1           ABC        1          $10    2018-01-01
2            1           ABC        1          $20    2018-02-01
3            1           ABC        1          $30    2018-03-01
4            2           ABC        2          $40    2018-04-01
5            2           ABC        2          $50    2018-05-01
6            3           ABC        3          $60    2018-06-01
7            3           ABC        3          $70    2018-07-01

Customer Table

Customer_ID    Call Date
1              2018-02-01
2              2018-05-01
3              2018-07-01
```

My challenge is that I want the query to work in a way that it picks up the date(Call Date) from the customer table and sum the values of payments made before the call date.

Comment: Please take a few moments and include all relevant sample table data _directly in the question_, formatted as text, not as images or image links.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry for the inconvenience. I have added the sample table data as text

Comment: @HasenCH It appears unclear to me this, as your query & table definition is conflicting among itself. Where does `first_name`, `last_name` belongs to? `payment` or `customer` table?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this query:

```
SELECT
    first_name, 
    last_name,
    call_date,
    customer_id, 
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN payment_date < call_date
        THEN amount
        ELSE 0
        END
    )
FROM
(
    Select 
        c.first_name, 
        c.last_name,
        c.call_date,
        p.customer_id, 
        p.amount
        p.payment_date
    From
        payment p JOIN customer c
            ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
) a

GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```

Hope it helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use column numbers in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. Use columns names or aliases.

Secondly, use explicit joins.

Thirdly, list in `GROUP BY` all columns that appear in the `SELECT` and have no aggregate function. Although MySQL doesn't require this, it's required by SQL standards and most other databases. And it is required for a reason. MySQL has finally addressed the problem and [starting with MySQL 5.7.5, the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled by default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-changes).

Now that's out of the way, you can use add the date condition to the joining condition:

```
SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name, p.customer_id, SUM(p.amount) AS total
FROM payment p
INNER JOIN customer c ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
                     AND p.payment_date < c.call_date
GROUP BY p.customer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name
ORDER BY total DESC
```